# Why does this Javascript Syntax work?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following code in one module :

```
export let person = {
     name : "henry",
     age :  5
}
```

in another module i import :

```
import {person} from './person'
```

When try to change person module:

```
person = {
     name : "joe",
     age : 20
 }
```

I get a syntax Error.
But when i change any property on the person object it does so successfully

```
person.name = "joe"  // works
person.age =50  //works
```

why is it so?

Comment: What error it is showing?

Comment: Import has equal rules to `const person = {...};` so you cant reassign it, however you can mutate it

Comment: Some sort of immutable object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you doing `import {person} from './person'` you are acctely getting `const person` with the exported object.

You cant change the content of your `person` object, but, becuse the only thing that is const in the case- is the [refrence to object](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0), you **can** change the content of the object itself.

For example:

```
const obj = {};
obj.stackoverflow = "Cool site"; // works!
obj = "stackoverflow"; //TypeError: Assignment to constant variable
```

Comment: const only rebukes assignments. i Think

Comment: First you are saying that the content of the object cannot be change and then you say it can be changed ;) I think you mean to say that you cannot *assign* a *new value* to the `person` *binding* (variable).